# How do I get a global afterEach in protractor that will run after every test to take a screenshot?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I would like to take a screenshot after every test I run so I added an afterEach to my protractor.config.js file's onPrepare function. It works successfully for the first test in each browser but screenshots are not taken for any subsequent tests. Any idea how to get an afterEach that will run after every single test in protractor using jasmine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel - use a third-party package - in case of `jasmine2`, it is [`protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter):

> Use the screenshot reporter to capture screenshots after each executed Protractor test case.

Comment: When I was first starting protractor I tried to use this and had some sort of issue configuring it to work correctly in my automated test workflow but coming back to it more experienced it was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!